# How to get deadlock detection details in NDB?

Tags: mysql

I need to get the information regarding deadlock occurrence in mysql cluster. Is there any command we can use to get latest deadlocks detection? (In mysql we can use SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS, so can we use same command or is there any other way of getting deadlock details)?

Answer (score 0):

NDB deadlock detection is implemented through a timeout. You can set the [TransactionDeadlockDetectionTimeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html) parameter for transactions.

You can refer to this link for more explanation: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?25,505712,505757#msg-505757

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.